# ObservableCollection of knowns entities of severals tables

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a question which seems too specific for google, or maybe I don't use the correct words; I find nothing about this.

I have severals tables and each of them contain several Entities (columns). Every tables has a Common Primary Key, we can use this column as a link for every table.

I want to pick some entities of a table, other entities of another table, other entities of another table, etc.. and send'em to a unique ObservableCollection, this ObservableCollection will be, in a second step, binded to a DataGrid.

I could create an `ObservableCollection` per table and then create a `CompositeCollection` of each `ObservableCollection` but I don't want to use the CompositeCollection, It doesn't display Datas as I want, I discovered this here([CompositeCollection binding on a DataGrid by MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907025/compositecollection-binding-on-a-datagrid-by-mvvm/25907443?noredirect=1#comment40551888_25907443))

How can I perform this? I have found lot of scripts but nothing about sending specific columns from specific tables on a unique ObservableCollection.

I hope I have been clear enough, If you want some code to illustrate, I can send what you want. But as it's a general question of a specific way to add datas on an ObservableCollection, I think it isn't necessary.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:

This is what my Database looks like:
(http://imagik.fr/view/123053)

Comment: With normal EF use, an entity isn't a column ... it is a row. You **can** map your entities though in other ways, using table-splitting or entity-splitting. Are the entities you are talking about the same kind of entity (e.g. Person) or are they all different kinds of entity (e.g. Person, Animal, Receipt etc)?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I don't master this well for the moment. If you'r speaking about the "Common Primary Key, we can use this column as a link for every table.", so yes, It's the same kind of entity (Varchar50) with the same name, PMRQTOTM

Comment: No, I'm not speaking about the key. I think the problem is you're mixing up your sql DB structures (columns, rows, tables) with your c# structures (entities) and the distinction between these isn't clear in your head. An entity is something like a `Person`, that has properties such as `Age`, `Gender`,`Date of Birth`, `Orders`. That entity, and its properties, may map to multiple tables in SQL and that is where EF comes in. I think you need to show some examples of what you mean by 'entity' and what your tables look like.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my code with my Sql structure. As you can see, TOTMPMRQ, or PMRQTOTM in some case, is the primarykey of each table and is common to every table. But I must admit, distinction between entities and tables aren't very clear for me X/

Comment: It is clear from your question that you are very inexperienced in programming. This website is not here to teach inexperienced users new languages and as such, I have voted to close this question for being to broad. A good answer that explained everything that you need to know would be far to long for this website. It is *your* responsibility to learn how to program on your own. When you can program and are stuck on a particular programming problem, please return to ask for help regarding that specific problem.

Comment: That is an EF diagram isn't it? Which means those are (currently) your entities. It looks like you've just got a direct mapping 1:1 with tables:entities. I can't really go fully into how to use EF, there are better places to learn that than an SO answer, but you should look at **entity splitting** which would suit your purpose I think. As you use the same keys across multiple tables you can combine those tables into a single entity. You **do** need to get a handle on what an entity is though. I have no idea what a PMRQTOTMGPS is! There must be a better word for what that is.

Comment: This is an Edit of the EF model: (http://www.imabox.fr/affiche?=a3=14190910595Iy8Wi52.PNG) with how the tables are supposed to interact with the others.  Thanks for all Mashton but Sheridan has right, I must master what I do more before coming here. My question wasn't specific enough. @Sheridan I know I'm a beginner, but it's not a reason to belittle myself like this.

Comment: *I know I'm a beginner, but it's not a reason to belittle myself like this*... I'm sorry that you feel that I have belittled you as that was not my intention. My intention was merely to point out to you that this website has [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and is *not* here to help absolute beginners. From the linked page: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face... Your questions should be **reasonably scoped**. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Comment: Understood. It isn't a problem, It's my bad. Understood, I'll come back with real question when questions I'll get. Greetings.